# Get value for selected button

Tags: html, angularjs

How to get ng-model value for only active button in angularjs

```
<div class="time_buttons mar_bot_30" ng-init="selectedBtn = 'minute'">
     <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active':selectedBtn === 'second'}" ng-click="selectedBtn = 'second'" ng-model="SECOND">Second</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active':selectedBtn === 'minute'}" ng-click="selectedBtn = 'minute'" ng-model="MINUTE">Minute</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active':selectedBtn === 'hour'}" ng-click="selectedBtn = 'hour'" ng-model="HOUR">Hour</button>
</div>
```

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="time_buttons mar_bot_30">
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active':selectedBtn === 'second'}" ng-click="selectedButton('Second')">Second</button>
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active':selectedBtn === 'minute'}" ng-click="selectedButton('Minute')" >Minute</button>
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active':selectedBtn === 'hour'}" ng-click="selectedButton('Hour')">Hour</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.selectedBtn = 'minute'
$scope.selectedButton = function(status) {
  console.log(status)
}
```

You need to call some function in ng-click and pass the parameter.No need of use ng-model in button.

here selectedBtn will give default value and after clicking selectedButton function will call and give u selected value

Comment: here i am not able to get default selected button value

Answer (score 0):

check using hasClass

```
angular.element(button).hasClass('active');
```

Refer [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)